Time Series Analysis and fitting in Python
I am working with two time-series obtained from a aquatic robot—one representing Depth vs. Time and the other Temperature vs. Time, with Time being the common factor between both series. All the data is labeled in a CSV file, and I’m using Jupyter Notebook for analysis.
Basically both these sensors are mounted on the same robot, so ideally both should be changing together.
From the graph, it’s evident that as depth increases, temperature should generally decrease (which is obvious as the robot goes deeper in the sea the temperature should decrease).
However, there seems to be a delay in the Temperature Sensor, because after approximately 4 seconds, depth remains relatively constant, but the temperature continues to decrease until around 15+ seconds (after which it gets somewhat linear).
My goal is to quantify this delay. Specifically, I want to determine the time constant (or compensation value) that I can use to adjust for the delayed temperature sensor, essentially finding how much time the temperature sensor needs to detect temperature changes at a specific depth. You can use any math techniques you think are valid for this, and if possible share with me, so even I can have a look
I’m thinking a Least Squares method or a mathematical fitting approach (or exponential smoothing) might work, but I’m not entirely sure, (If you guys have any better approach please let me know).
Any insights on the best way to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!
I created a google drive link where I will upload both all files for reference.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u0dLJTqJ0HSRgglT3aqwOqiglX5lpE7c?usp=sharing
Thanks in adv.

Hey, your question can be significantly improved if you supply what you have tried so far and the data if possible. If not possible, try to mimick the data by some imitation values. For more information, please see how to ask a good question. Won't hurt to take the tour as well

Welcome to SO, could you post the dataset (no screenshot, link or copy paste it).

Please check the updated post and any help would be appreciated... If you still have doubts, I can answer any of your questions. Thanks again.

Thanks for the update. But still I'm not convinced how you could be sure there is a 'delay' in that sensor? How could you be certain the depth data captured by the sensor is somewhat wrong? And if it is certainly wrong and there is a delay, what is your expected result or plot of the depth data? If it is supposed to be decreasing, how much are you expecting, which I think is the goal of this question? If so, we need to see the spec of the sensor that has captured depth so that we could formulate what could have gone wrong, I think

Thanks for replying, I never said there’s a delay in the Depth sensor, the delay is in the temperature sensor, if you see the graph the temperature sensor isn’t getting linear until like 15+ seconds, whereas the the robot has been sitting at a constant depth from around 4 seconds.. so this (time) delay that the temperature sensor takes to get linear is what I need to find

It seems your temperature sensor has a large raise time and therefore needs more time to reach its correct value than your depth sensor. Do you have an idea of 95% Full Scale raise time for the sensor?

Nah, I mean I can fix the sensor as I don't own the robot, I just need to determine, the delay in temperature sensor using the data that I currently have.
